# Vue Native "Element type is invalid: expected a string" on ActionBar

Tags: expo, vue-native

I've just worked through the "getting started" tutorial for vue native, and have my device set up running my vue native app in EXPO.

I wanted to add a toolbar, so I looked up how to do this, and found the `ActionBar` element, so I added it in my code like so:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActionBar title="main menu">

        </ActionBar>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But I got the following error:

> Can't find variable: ActionBar

So I tried to fix the error myself by changing this line

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

to be

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActionBar } from 'react-native';
```

But now I am getting the error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined

Please help me to find how to import `ActionBar` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no ActionBar component is react native if you still want to use ActionBar so you can use this library [react-native-action-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-action-bar)